# Using TransferUtility to upload a images to S3 is incredibly slow

Tags: android, kotlin, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload nearly 100 images to amazon s3. But the uploading speed is really slow. Some users have reported similar issues. In IOS its takes only few seconds to upload all 100 but in Android it's taking more than a minute to upload all. Please help me to understand what's the issue here.

so here i am initialising AmazonS3Client,

```
  val configuration = ClientConfiguration()
        configuration.maxErrorRetry = 10
        configuration.maxConnections = 100
        configuration.connectionTimeout = 0
        configuration.socketTimeout = 0

        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this, object : com.amazonaws.mobile.client.Callback<UserStateDetails> {
            override fun onResult(userStateDetails: UserStateDetails) {}
            override fun onError(e: Exception) {}
        })
        credentials = BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY,SECRET_KEY)
        s3Client = AmazonS3Client(credentials,configuration)
        s3Client!!.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1))   

        transferUtility = TransferUtility.builder()
                .context(this).awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().configuration)
                .s3Client(s3Client)
                .build()
```

and looping the below uploading process,

```
val uploadObserver = transferUtility.upload(bucketname, toRemoteKey, aLocalFile, md, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)
           uploadObserver.setTransferListener(object : TransferListener {
               override fun onStateChanged(
                       id: Int,
                       state: TransferState
               ) {
                   if (TransferState.FAILED == state) {  } 
                   else if (TransferState.COMPLETED == state) { }
               }

               override fun onProgressChanged(
                       id: Int,
                       bytesCurrent: Long,
                       bytesTotal: Long
               ) {
                 
               }

               override fun onError(id: Int, exception: Exception) {

               }
           })
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the question and try to include the code. Without code, there is nothing much can be done

Comment: @SharukhMohammed posted the code